# Optimization Problem Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, optimization

I am interested in learning if the following is a canonical problem, or if there is a good reference for it. It seems like something that might appear in a textbook, but you never really know with this sort of thing! I ask because I'm having trouble searching for this in particular.

Let $K$ be a set of lights each with a separate battery and charger. Each lamp constantly charges at a rate $\beta$ and, when turned on, expends energy at a rate $\alpha$. Each battery starts containing $\epsilon$ power. If we can turn the lights on and off arbitrarily, what is the longest time we can run $l$ lights for, assuming that such an amount of time is finite? That is, we can turn lights off to let them charge and turn them back on, as long as there are always $l$ running.

In particular, what is a sequence of switch flicks that achieves this time?

Comment: I would imagine that this is solvable directly, something like finding the largest $T$ such that $\epsilon + T (\beta - { l \over K} (\alpha + \beta)) \ge 0$?

Comment: I realize now that more I'm interested in generating an explicit way of switch flicking that achieves such a bound. How to do this seemed less clear to me.

Comment: Unless there is a cost for switching a light, I think a scheme should be straightforward to create.

Comment: I don't recognise this as a canonical problem. It would be related to 'duty-cycle' problems/analysis. If switching had a cost (time or energy) it might fall into an optimal control framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $\alpha >0$.

We must have $\epsilon>0$ because if not, then we cannot switch any lights on.

If we run the lights for time $T$, then we must have
$K\epsilon + T((K-L)\beta -L \alpha) \ge 0$ (that is, the initial energy plus any energy added must be greater than or equal to the energy used).

If we let $\sigma_i:[0,T] \to \{0,1\}$ represent whether light $i$ is on (1) or off (0), then the constraints are $\sum_{i=0}^K \sigma_i(t) = L$ for $t \in [0,T]$, and the net energy available to light $i$ must be non-negative for $t \in [0,T]$, that is, if 
$e_i(t) = \epsilon + \beta \int_0^t (1-\sigma_i(\tau)) d \tau - \alpha \int_0^t \sigma_i(\tau) d \tau $, then we require $e_i(t) \ge 0$ for $t \in [0,T]$.

I will call a switching strategy $\sigma_i$ on $[0,T]$ 'reasonable' if the number of toggles is finite, $\sum_{i=0}^K \sigma_i(t) = L$ and $e_i(t) \ge 0$ for all $t \in [0,T]$.

If we let $T_* = \sup \{ T |K\epsilon + T((K-L)\beta -L \alpha) \ge 0  \}$, then it is easy to see that $T_* = \begin{cases} {K \epsilon \over L \alpha - (K-L)\beta }, & \text{if }(K-L)\beta -L \alpha < 0 \\ \infty, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then I claim that if $T < T_*$, then there is a reasonable switching strategy.

Note that if $T < T_*$, then $\inf_{t \in [0,T]} K\epsilon + t((K-L)\beta -L \alpha) > 0$, or, in other words, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that
$\epsilon + t (\beta (1-{L\over K}) - \alpha {L \over K}) \ge \delta$ for $t \in [0,T]$.

Let $\sigma$ be the 1-periodic signal $\sigma(t) = 1_{[0, {L \over K})+ \mathbb{Z}}(t)$.

Choose $\Delta>0$: Then the idea is that each light will be on for $L\Delta$ over a period $K \Delta$, with each light having a different 'phase'. If we choose $\Delta$ small enough, then each light is on for approximately ${L \over K} $ of the time (cf. PWM, dithering, or at a stretch, relaxed controls). For $i=0,...,K-1$ define $\sigma_i(t,\Delta) = \sigma({t-i \Delta \over K \Delta})$. Then light $i$ will be turned on at time $t$ **iff** $\phi_i(t,\Delta) = 1$. 
It is easy to check that $\sum_{i=0}^K \sigma_i(t,\Delta) = L$ for all $t$.

The net energy available at time $t$ is given by
$e_i(t) = \epsilon + \beta \int_0^t (1-\sigma_i(\tau,\Delta)) d \tau - \alpha \int_0^t \sigma_i(\tau,\Delta) d \tau $.
Note that $\lim_{\Delta \downarrow 0} \sup_{t \in [0,T]} \left| \int_0^t \phi_i(\tau, \Delta) d \tau - {L \over K}t \right| = 0$, and if we let
$e(t) = \epsilon + t (\beta (1-{L\over K}) - \alpha {L \over K})$, then
$e_i \to e$ uniformly in $t \in [0,T]$.
Since $e(t) \ge \delta >0$ for all $t$, we see that there is some $\Delta>0$ such that $t \mapsto \sigma_i(t,\Delta)$ is a reasonable switching strategy.

As an aside, we note that if $T = T_* < \infty$, then there can be no reasonable strategy, as $K-L$ lights must be off for some small interval near the end and their energy is 'wasted'.

I would guess that if if $T_* < \infty$ and we allow for countable switchings, then we can find a suitable strategy on $[0,T_*]$.